# How to make a rest API Call post with multiple parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am trying to have an API Call post. I can use this post command however my issue is that I have multiple parameters such as, Name, phone number, email, and multiple other private information. I have tried this method in order to get it to work but have not been successful. Thank you in advance for any help!

GET Request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
[manager GET:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

or

POST URL-Form-Encoded Request

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: Your answer lies here (top voted one) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20794573/afnetworking-2-0-send-post-request-with-url-parameters/23660823#23660823 . In short `PUT` requests don't work by default with parameters in AFNetworking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"key_param2":@"obj_param2", @"key_param3":@"obj_param3",@"key_paramN":@"obj_paramN"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: From my understanding, with my parameters: 
{
    "partner_key": "VxYkMw3N8E",
    "auth_token": "QaU9QcFZ6xE7aiRRBge0wZ4p6E01GEbl",
    "payment_account_id": "",
    "card_number": "1111222233334444",
    "card_exp_date": "122019",
    "amount": "5012",
    "memo": "Landscaping",
    "recipient": {
         "email": "recipient@acculynk.com",
         "mobile_phone": "5555231234"
       }
}

Comment: I'm getting confused at the last part that is needed to enter the ""recipient": { "email": "recipient@acculynk.com", "mobile_phone": "5555231234" } }

How would I enter that? Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To add more parameters, just include them in your parameters dictionary like so:

```
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar", @"otherFoo":@"otherBar"};
```

Then pass 'parameters' to your post method exactly as you are currently doing.

Comment: For some reason, I'm getting a "API - General Exception" error message. There is something wrong with that code, any ideas? Its reaching the server but its having an error converting it into an object when I check the logs for the server.

Comment: That probably means the server is expecting the params to be in a certain format. You'll need to check the server-side exception for details on what it wants, and change the parameters dictionary to match.